# Why is "int arr[n];" causing my program to hang when the index "n" is to be inputted later by scanf()?

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

Why does the following program `program1`,intended to print numbers `1-9` hang and closes abruptly even though it compiles without error?I suspect it has got something to do with the fact that I have used a variable as the index of the integer array `arr[]`.I expect the user to be prompted to enter the size of the array and based on that I fill up that array.Though I can intuitively pinpoint the cause of the problem here is the variable index, I want to know the reason for the following:

**Why does the program compile without error or warning if it's faulty?**

**What is the technical reason why the code is wrong?** Can't we use a variable as an array index?Is there a way for it or `malloc()` is the **only** solution?

```
//Program1

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n,arr[n],i;
printf("Enter the size of n");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
arr[i]=i;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
```

I have achieved the same using `malloc()` in `program2` and the program works fine with it.But I want to know the reason why the above program `program1` fails,instead of blindly using `malloc()` just because it's so convenient.

```
//Program2

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int n,*ptr,i;
printf("Enter the size of array\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
ptr=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
ptr[i]=i;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("%d\n",ptr[i]);

free(ptr);

}
```

Comment: FYI, `clang` does warn about this.

Comment: @Mat I have to change the settings of my compiler then.I got no error or warning at all.Can you tell me what warnings your `clang` gave?

Comment: @Mat It would be really helpful if you could tell me what warnings your compiler `clang` gave about it.

Comment: For clang, compiling with `-Wmost` is a good setting to start with. That turns on a reasonable set of warnings. If you are ambitious, also use `-Werror`, especially when starting new programs. That turns warnings into errors, forcing you to fix problems before you can proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int arr[n]` says, "Use `n` to specify the number of elements for this array". However, at that point, the value of the variable `n` is undefined. I have absolutely no idea why your compiler is letting you get away with that, but Undefined Behaviour is why your program isn't working correctly. Using malloc is the correct way to go in this case.

Comment: The compiler is letting them get away with it because they have not turned warnings on and the compiler defaults to do-what-you-want-see-if-I-care mode. Compilers ought to default to most warnings on and only allow you to turn them off if you have a cryptographically signed certificate from a licensed computer science instructor. :-)

Comment: You don't *have* to use `malloc`. You could just do the `scanf` first and then declare `int arr[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing `arr` before the size is known. just because you declare `n` beforehand doesnt mean n has a value.

Answer (score 0):

`int arr[n]` is a variable definition. Those are evaluated at compile time, based on the value of n then. The value of n is indeterminate, so the size of the array is kind of random - frankly I'm surprised it compiled, and doubly surprised if it compiled without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Declare arr[n] after scanf ....